Check if var is a real number (include float and negative) without regular expresions in Bash
I am trying to solve a riddle in bash in an exercise that given 3 arguments, the third being optional, check that argument is a real number, but I can't use regular expressions, grep, awk...
How can I check if I can't use a regular expression? I also thought of using -gt and -le but it only works with integers.
I saw a post here similar to this but it doestn work with float or negative without regular expression
Thank you very much.
if [ $# -ge 3 ] && [[ $3 != *[!0-9]* ]]; then
    echo "Error: optional third argument is not a valid frequency"
    exit 1
fi


isNumber(){ { LC_NUMERIC=C printf %f "$@" > /dev/null;} 2>/dev/null;}

!= is not a regex in bash - it's a negative glob match. Similar, but not the same.

Silly question: Why don't you want to use a regex? Is this a programming exercise, or why do you want to do it the hard way, when bash comes with a useful extended regex matching builtin?

Let's assume that a "valid" real literal is one of:

an integer (42)
a dot followed by an integer (.42)
an integer followed by a dot, followed by an integer (42.42)

optionally preceded by a + or - sign. Then, if you are allowed to use extended glob:
shopt -s extglob
if (( $# == 3 )) && [[ "$3" != ?([-+])?([0-9]).+([0-9]) ]] && [[ "$3" != ?([-+])+([0-9]) ]]; then
    echo "Error: optional third argument is not a valid frequency"
    exit 1
fi


Hi, Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me how it construct? [[ "$3" != ?([-+])?([0-9]).+([0-9]) ]] && [[ "$3" != ?([-+])+([0-9]) ]];

The best resource for this is the bash manual itself (man bash). You can also read this page of the bash guide.

POSIX-shell grammar solution without pattern matching that work for arbitrary int or float detection:
#!/usr/bin/env sh

isNumber(){ { LC_NUMERIC=C printf %f "$@" > /dev/null;} 2>/dev/null;}
isInt(){ { LC_NUMERIC=C printf %d "$@" > /dev/null;} 2>/dev/null;}
isFloat() { isNumber "$@" && ! isInt "$@";}

for v in hello 42 3.14 'foo bar' 2.99E16 1E-20; do
  if isNumber "$v"
  then
    printf '%s is a number\n' "$v"
    isInt "$v" && printf '%s is an integer\n' "$v"
    isFloat "$v" && printf '%s is a float\n' "$v"
  else printf '%s is not a number\n' "$v"
  fi
done

Result:
hello is not a number
42 is a number
42 is an integer
3.14 is a number
3.14 is a float
foo bar is not a number
2.99E16 is a number
2.99E16 is a float
1E-20 is a number
1E-20 is a float


Hi, thank you for your answer. I dont understant the functions isNumber(), how it check if argument is a number? Best regards.

It tries to print format as float %f/ printf will fail if argument is  not number

oh right! im going to read about printf in bash for learn arguments. And is it possible to do the print inside the if ? so i dont need the function, like if {printf %f "$2" > /dev/null;} 2>/dev/null; then...

it would all work inline with the if condition. Although It would be much less readable and the intention much less obvious than offloading it into a dedicated function with a meaningful name.
